# Using OpenCV python binding to display webcam stream in PySide widget

Tags: python, opencv, pyside

Hey if anyone could help me it would be great. I'm trying to use OpenCV to take webcam stream and then display it in a PySide application by updating an image.

```
cv.NamedWindow('Raw', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
self.cap = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

This is working and I update the named window in a while loop with the show image function.

```
while True:
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.cap)
    img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U,1)
    if frame is None:
        print "Frame is none"
        sys.exit(1)
    # display webcam image
    cv.ShowImage('Raw', frame)
```

But when I try to display the images in a PySide application I just see a blank black image 
(The following code is in the same while loop as above)

```
image = QImage(frame.tostring(), frame.width, frame.height, QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
grid = QGridLayout()
grid.setSpacing(10)
imageBox = QLabel(self)
imageBox.setGeometry(0,0,300,200)
imageBox.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(300,200))
grid.addWidget(imageBox)
self.widget.setLayout(grid)
self.repaint()
```

Does anyone know why the image doesn't update?